# Which certificate signing request information is included in a certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, csr

If you create a certificate signing request and include the identifying information (e.g. Distinguished Name, Business name, Town/City, e-mail address), is any of this data included in the certificate itself (which the CA issues to you based on the CSR)?

Or is it simply used by the certificate authority to identify you before agreeing to sign the public key?

For a more full list of identifying information see the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request

Comment: The issued certificate is largely identical to the CSR apart from the issuer and signature information.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on CA configuration and request generation code. For example, when working with Microsoft Enterprise CA public key and certificate template name is sufficient. CA server will look into certificate template properties (including subject name) to construct certificate. When working with Microsoft Standalone CA, all required extensions, subject field must be provided explicitly in the request.
Commercial CAs may require different set of information to construct the certificate.

It is about CA requirements. Request generation code may put additional information which may (not necessary) be used by CA to construct certificate. For example, certreq.exe or CertEnroll COM interfaces include request originator information: user account name, host name, process name and default extensions (KeyUsage) based on key settings (AT_EXCHANGE or AT_SIGNATURE).

In other word, there is no definite answer to this question. Everything depends on client and server software. Different client software may include different information.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the CA, but a good CA should not copy what you've put in your CSR blindly.

When a CA issues a certificate, it effectively vouches for the identity information and attributes it puts in the certificate. Therefore, it shouldn't put data such as organisation name, location, e-mail address unless it has been able to verify them externally. It's a good thing from a security point of view in principle, and since they generally make you pay extra for additional attributes, it's also in their commercial interest not to let you choose what goes in.

In practice, it depends on the type of certificate you go for (e.g. domain-validated, EV certificate, ...). The extra pieces of informations will generally be verified by the CA through some administrative process, so what's in the CSR itself is barely relevant, since they'll construct the CA based on whatever information they will be willing to assert.

For example, for domain-validated certificates, some CAs will construct a DN like `OU=Domain Validated, CN=your.host.name`, irrespectively of the DN you've actually put in the CSR. They might even throw in a couple of Subject Alternative Names, with and without the `www.` prefix automatically.